# How to use regular expressions in class path in TestNG.xml file

Tags: java, regex, testng

I am using Java and TestNG to write a Selenium test. I noticed that I cannot use `*` in my path this way: `<class name="test.*.testcase01" />`.

Is there any way to make this work? I also tried `<class name="test..*.testcase01" />`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here using the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use regex in the class name attribute with TestNG xml. Regex can be used in `include`, `exclude` tags and `package` tags. So to make this work you can do one of these:

```
<classes>
 <class name="test.YOUR_PACKAGE.testclass>
  <methods>
    <include name=".*testcase01"/>
  </methods>
  </class>
</classes>
```

Here the `*` will include every method in your class that ends with `testcase01`.

Or:

```
<suite name="Suite One">
  <test name="Test One" >
     <packages>
        <package name="test.*" />
     </packages>
  </test>
</suite>
```

`*` here will include all classes under test package.

Comment: Can I exclude classes someway?